# How can I automate restarting a vmware vm

Tags: crash, vmware-player

I have a vm that does nothing but run magic jack. Magic jack doesn't run perfectly in a vm. It works great for days then randomly the vm reboots. except it doesn't come up clean. It gets to the windows splash screen and hangs spinning the cpu.

I don't care how I solve the problem (although not crashing in the first place would be ideal) but I just need the vm  to reboot cleanly when it does crash.

Is there a windows registry setting I can say "on crash, reboot" or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

If there's no other solution, perhaps you can get a jump on the crashing and reboot the VM nightly. Create a scheduled task that runs "`shutdown -r -t 0`" at 3:00am or some other opportune time. Hopefully the VM will come up clean after these regular reboots.